# Linear transformation of variable under the integral sign. Easy change of variables question

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I realize this might be a basic question, but I need a sanity check.

Let $f(\vec{x})$ be a function that takes $n$-dimensional vectors and returns a real number. Suppose the goal is to compute
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(\vec{x})\, d\vec{x},$$
but in fact it is easier to work with the transformed variable $T\vec{x}$, where $T$ is some $n\times n$ matrix. What exactly is the change of variables procedure for 
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(T(\vec{x}))\, d\vec{x}?$$

Do you simply divide the second integral by $\det(T)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)\ dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(Tx)|\det T|\ dx.$$
Don't forget the absolute value!

EDIT: Obviously this only works if $T$ is invertible.

Comment: You must mean divide. For example, let $f(x)=x$ and take $T=3$.

Comment: No, I mean multiply. Your example function is not integrable over $\mathbb{R}$. Think about the way you first learn about integration by substitution: if $a>0$, let $x=ay$ and so $dx=ady$, hence $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(ay)ady$.

Comment: You can use my example without the loss of generality since you can define the function to be zero outside of [0,1]. I think you are misremembering the rule: Since $y=3x, dy=3dx$, so $dx=dy/3$.

Comment: Ah, but now the limits of integration are not all of $\mathbb{R}$. If we replace $\mathbb{R}^n$ by a subset $A$ in the first integral, we must replace $\mathbb{R}^n$ by $T^{-1}(A)$ in the second. So in your example we have $\int_0^1xdx=\frac12$ and $\int_0^{1/3}(3x)\cdot3dx=9\cdot\frac{x^2}2\bigg|_{x=0}^{1/3}=\frac12$. If it helps you understand, replace all instances of $x$ by $y$ in the second integral to make the substitution "$x=Ty$" explicit.

Comment: You are right! Apologies. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer uses the same name for the transformed variable, which can be confusing for some. Let's call $\vec{y} = T \vec{x}$. Then
\begin{align*}
    \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(\vec{x}) d \vec{x} &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(T^{-1}\vec{y}) \frac{1}{|\det T | } d \vec{y} 
\end{align*}
and also
\begin{align*}
    \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(T\vec{x}) d \vec{x} &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(\vec{y}) \frac{1}{|\det T|} d \vec{y}
\end{align*}